# Is it possible to exceute a method from a different application in Java?

Tags: java, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate some manual tests for a desktop app written in Java. I'm using [FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org) to do this. Is it possible to execute some parts of the code on the app being tested from FEST and get the results back in a stream or something. Or is there any other testing framework that lets you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [FEST reflection module](http://fest.easytesting.org/reflect/wiki/pmwiki.php).

There is a method called `staticMethod` that lest you do it.

Example

```
String xml = staticMethod("staticMethodName")
                            .withReturnType(String.class)
                            .in(Class.forName("com.package.className"))
                            .invoke();

return xml;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) for testing everything in any Java application, it writes the results in a hmtl set of documents for an easy consulting.

Try use this framework. For a good ref i advice you [O'Reilly Pocket Ref](http://books.google.it/books?id=Ur_zMK0WQwIC&lpg=PP1&dq=Junit&pg=PP8#v=onepage&q&f=false).